# GROUP BY and ORDER BY on JOINed table - complex and slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The story is like this... I have `Users` and they have `Children`.
I want to send every day using a CRON JOB coupons to users that have children between child birth dates interval.
I want to know who will be the user to get the coupon and for which child.
also i want to send only one coupon for each child and the child must be the youngest that the user has.

I have the following tables

```
Children
+--------------------------------------+
- Primary Key: childrenID (int)
- Index: userID (int)
- Index: childBirthDate (date)
+--------------------------------------+
- childrenID - userID - childBirthDate -
- 1          - 1      - 21/01/2000     -
- 2          - 1      - 01/11/2013     -
- 3          - 1      - 25/10/2013     -
- 4          - 2      - 01/11/2013     -
- 5          - 3      - 01/11/2013     -
+--------------------------------------+

Users
+------------------------+
- Primary Key: userID (int)
- Index: categoryGroup (varchar)
+------------------------+
- userID - categoryGroup -
- 1      - 'Group1'      -
- 2      - 'Group1'      -
- 3      - 'Group2'      -
- 4      - 'Group2'      -
+------------------------+

CuponRequests
+------------------------+
- Primary Key: ID (int)
- Index: userID (int)
- Index: cuponID (int)
+-----------------------+
- ID - cuponID - userID -
- 1  - 1       - 1      -
- 1  - 2       - 1      -
- 1  - 1       - 2      -
+-----------------------+
```

This is basically the three main tables with the relevant columns
I have the following SQL query to execute and fetch the results I need.

```
SELECT users.userID,
       users.categoryGroup children.childBirthDate,
       children.childrenID
FROM users,
  (SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT children.childrenID,
             children.childBirthDate,
             users.userID AS child_uid
      FROM children,
           users
      WHERE children.userID = users.userID
      ORDER BY children.childBirthDate DESC)t1
   GROUP BY child_uid)children
WHERE (children.childBirthDate <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH))
  AND (children.childBirthDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE() , INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
  AND (children.child_uid = users.userID)
  AND ('Group1, Group2' LIKE CONCAT('%', users.categoryGroup, '%'))
  AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT userID,
            cuponID
     FROM cuponRequests
     WHERE userID = users.userID
       AND cuponID = 1)
  AND userID = 1
ORDER BY children.childBirthDate DESC
```

For this query I am trying to work only on one user and on only one coupon
but on it's natural behavior - the query is working on all the users

the "cuponID", and the intervals, come from the PHP side of the script - I iterate the "cupons" table (It's not mentioned here) and executed this query on every "coupon" row)

The problem is that this query is being executed for about 1.5 seconds (O.O)
except for running this script at a CRON JOB environment, this script also runs right after the user is registered to the website. I have 96 cupons - this makes slows down the registration for about a minutes (which is ALOT)

---

I figured that the this query

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT children.childrenID,
          children.childBirthDate,
          users.userID AS child_uid
   FROM children,
        users
   WHERE children.userID = users.userID
   ORDER BY children.childBirthDate DESC)t1
GROUP BY child_uid
```

slows things down. I tried to do a JOIN instead off a select query inside a select query like this:

```
FROM users LEFT JOIN children ON children.userID = users.userID
```

But then I lose the "ORDER BY childBirthDate DESC" to get the youngest child of this user and I lose the "GROUP BY child_uid" to get only one of his children

Any ideas how to make things faster but still working?

P.S
Sorry for my lack of English.

---

Edit:

Here is the output of EXPLAIN SQL

```
+----+--------------------+---------------+-------+----------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id |    select_type     |     table     | type  | possible_keys  |   key   | key_len |             ref              | rows  |                        Extra                        |
+----+--------------------+---------------+-------+----------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | NULL          | NULL  | NULL           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                         | NULL  | Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | cuponRequests | ref   | userID,cuponID | userID  | 5       | const                        | 1     | Using where                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED            | <derived3>    | ALL   | NULL           | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                         | 73526 | Using temporary; Using filesort                     |
|  3 | DERIVED            | users         | index | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL                         | 69271 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort        |
|  3 | DERIVED            | children      | ref   | userID         | userID  | 4       | users.userID                 | 1     |                                                     |
+----+--------------------+---------------+-------+----------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What are your INDEXes? if any

Comment: Are your dates stored using a DATE data type? Also, "i want to send only one cupon for each child and the child must be the oldest the user has." - the oldest legible child, or the oldest child, full stop?

Comment: Added INDEXes to the question

Comment: The Dates are DATE data type

Comment: Strawberry - i fixed the question. i should give the youngest one. and yes - the youngest ligible child (which means his user is in the categoryGroup that this cupon is and the youngest child is between the dates interval of the cupon dates)

Comment: What's the output of `EXPLAIN <your sql statement>`

Comment: I edited the question and added the output of EXPLAIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should be much faster. I've moved condition about birth dates.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT children.childrenID,
          children.childBirthDate,
          users.userID AS child_uid
   FROM children,
        users
   WHERE children.userID = users.userID
   AND children.childBirthDate <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH)
   AND children.childBirthDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE() , INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
   ORDER BY children.childBirthDate DESC)t1
GROUP BY child_uid
```

**EDIT**

The full query in the fastest form I could write. I have removed `%` from `LIKE`, changed sub-queries to joins and dropped `*`. Condition about birth dates are moved too. There could be errors, though.

```
SELECT users.userID,
   users.categoryGroup, children.childBirthDate,
   children.childrenID
FROM
  (SELECT MIN(childBirthDate) AS childBirthDate, userID
      FROM children
      WHERE childBirthDate <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH)
      AND childBirthDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE() , INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
      GROUP BY userID) AS ch1
  INNER JOIN users ON users.userID = ch1.userID
  INNER JOIN children ON users.userID = children.userID AND ch1.childBirthDate = children.childBirthDate
  LEFT JOIN CuponRequests ON CuponRequests.userID = userID AND cuponID = 1
  WHERE ('Group1' LIKE users.categoryGroup OR 'Group2' LIKE users.categoryGroup)
  AND CuponRequest.ID IS NULL
  AND userID = 1
ORDER BY children.childBirthDate DESC
```

**The long description**

- The sub-queries may be slow. Sometimes the optimizer will fail to do right stuff. Writing joins with `ON` clause should be more safe.
- The statements with `GROUP BY` are even more complicated for optimizers. It may help to write additional conditions inside them.
- It is very hard to use indexes for `LIKE '%something%'` statements. The `LIKE 'something%'` or `LIKE 'something'` are much faster.
- Sometimes it is good idea to change `*` to explicit list of needed arguments. Sometimes all needed informations are in indexes and there is no need to read directly from table. It may help a little in corner cases.

Comment: This made it faster ! every query executes at about 1.1 seconds for a query (+/-). but it still leaves me with 80 seconds loading time.

Comment: Wow! Sub total 1.1 seconds for all the 100 cupons (was ~2 minutes)

Comment: Can you please explain what you did and why this helped?

Comment: I've added long description to my answer. I don't know what exactly helped.